# Least squares estimate of a linear system of simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider the following simultaneous system

$$
y_{1} =\beta _{1}y_{2}+\alpha _{1}z+u_{1} \\
y_{2} =\beta _{2}y_{1}+\alpha _{2}z+u_{2}
$$

where $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$ and $z$ are vectors of random variables each of length $n$. $u_{1}$
and $u_{2}$ are residuals and all greek letters are coefficients to be estimated.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model) entry on the simultaneous equation model mentions the possibility to estimate all simultaneous equations at once. For
large systems, this will be computationally costly but for smaller ones this
seems a reasonable alternative.

**Question**: What is the best way to estimate (by least squares) the system at once?

Crossposting: A couple of days ago, I have posted the same question on [stats/stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506074). So far, the question has not received any answers or comments there.